# Return array after resolve promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, protractor, automated-tests

I'm trying to resolve my problem, but I don't have anymore ideas.
I want to create function to return array of values according of type variable.

I want to check that the parameter which is sent to function is an array of string or array of webelements, and I want to return this array to other function to sort it.

**Here is my code:**

```
  private static returnByType(unSortedElements) {
      var i = 0;
      var unSorted = [];
      if (typeof unSortedElements[0] === 'string') {
          unSorted = unSortedElements;
          return unSorted;
      } else {
          return unSortedElements.each((eachName) => {
              eachName.getText().then((name) => {
                  unSorted[i] = name;
                  i++;
              })
          })

      }

  }
```

If I pass string array to this function, it returns array with this strings, but when I pass there a list of webelements I get an empty array (in else block).
How I should return unSorted from else block?

Comment: First of all, you cannot synchronously return the result of an asynchronous function call. If you're making an asynchronous function call in your function, you also need to asynchronously await that in the caller. But since it's madness to have a function return either a synchronous or an asynchronous result, you should standardise that to always return an asynchronous result, even for the string case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with promise, you can't just return value, it will always be a promise. Your code should be probably something like this:

```
private static returnByType(unSortedElements) {
  var i = 0;
  var unSorted = [];
  if (typeof unSortedElements[0] === 'string') {
      unSorted = unSortedElements;
      // Promise.resolve(unSorted) to unify with else
      return Promise.resolve(unSorted);
  } else {
      // return type will be Promise<[]>
      return Promise.all(unSortedElements.map((eachName) => eachName.getText()));
  }

}
```

Return type of the function now will be `Promise<[]>`. Then you can use it like:

```
returnByType(args).then((unsorted) => ...);
```

- for `Promise.all()` refer to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).
- for `Promise.resolve()` refer to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

Comment: definitely agree with returning a promise in both branches to simplify calling the function

Comment: thanks! It's looks so easy:) But I have one problem, when I passed list of webelements ($$) and try to use this tunction in other:         `this.returnByType(unSortedElements).then((unsorted) =>  {
        console.log(unsorted)
        });`
then in console I get an error

`nhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at Function.returnByType (/home/kamil/projects/automation-tests/tmp/utils/Sort.js:18:28`

Comment: That error does not say much things. You have to show what is the type and where `unSortedElements` comes from. The code from the answer will work if `unSortedElements` is an array of some objects whose `getText()` return a promise.

Comment: unSortedElements is the list of titles of sections on page i get it by `unSortedElements = $$('.adm-chart .card-title')`

Comment: As I said before, once to this function `returnByType` will be passed array with text, other time will be passed list of webelements. Te sorting function will use this one to sort retrurned values instead of its type (text array or webelement array)

Comment: @gagatek, make jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ or something, otherwise it is unclear what is you after. your initial question was regarding use of promises and it should be solved by now.

Comment: ok, so block of `IF` works ok, but problem is in block `ELSE` so focus on this part - else is run if to this function is passed list of webelements(protractor) with text.
Hope this will help you to understand
http://jsfiddle.net/do6Lb7xs/

Comment: that is no different what you are writing here. `jsfiddle` is to make running code. any way, you have to make sure that `getText` is returning promise. other wise there is no input, on what is `$$`, `.adm-chart`, `.card-title` etc. it can be literally anything in the world. this works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/520dzLmj/, press Run and watch the console.

Comment: How I can check that getText return this promise?
I now I did 
`...
            return Promise.all(unSortedElements.map((eachName) => eachName.getText().then(someText => {
                console.log(someText);
            })));`
and I get an error
`(node:25312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at Function.returnByType (/home/kamil/projects/automation-tests/tmp/utils/Sort.js:19:28)`

but console.log printed me properly values

Comment: At worst, `console.log` everything you want to see, `console.log(eachName)`, `console.log(eachName.getText())` in appropriate places.

Comment: I dont understand what I make wrong. It looks like this promise is not returned properly... But dont know why.
`unSortedElements.getText().then(txt => {
console.log(txt)})` display in console properly text

Comment: `var values = this.returnByType(unSortedElements).then(values => { console.log(values); return values; });`

Comment: i Get 
 `Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` ... ;/

Comment: @gagatek, make a working `jsfiddle` of your case. otherwise no one will productively understand you. working, meaning that pressing `run` on `jsfiddle` will give error as you see it.

Comment: I cannot do this becouse it is a protractor framework, i cannot use element locators in jsfiddle

Comment: btw `unSortedElements = $$('.adm-chart .card-title')` returns only one promise